# Unable to access TCP ports via 1:1 NAT address

Tags: linux, pfsense

My setup:

- pfSense - WAN IP 1.2.3.4
- Linux server - LAN IP 192.168.1.5.

pfSense is set to 1:1 NAT the WAN IP 4.5.6.7 to 192.168.1.5, so that I can access the Linux server from outside the LAN.

I am able to open 4.5.6.7 to ICMP requests, and that is working fine; I can ping the Linux server using the WAN address.

However, I cannot get a connection to the HTTP server running on port 80 on the Linux server via the WAN address. I'm 100% sure I have opened the port correctly in pfSense's firewall. I have also tried adding a firewall rule that allow all traffic, regardless of source and destination, effectively disabling the firewall, and I am still unable to access port 80 on the Linux server via the WAN IP address.

To summarize:

192.168.1.5:80 - works fine

4.5.6.7:80 - times out, even with firewall disabled

Comment: Are you seeing the traffic arrive at pfsense on port 80?  Have you run a tcpdump?

Comment: Yes, the traffic is definitely arriving at pfSense on port 80, it just never makes it past that. The Linux server is not running any sort of firewall, so I'm pretty sure I've just misconfigured something in pfSense.

Comment: Can you see the NAT in the state table?  In `pfctl -ss`?

Comment: Yes, both for requests coming in, and for requests going out. The 4.5.6.7 address and the 192.168.1.5 address are being translated back and forth, so the NAT'ing is working correctly in both directions.

Comment: Actually, I'm now finding that even just a simple port forward is not working... I am also now noticing that DNS resolution doesn't work on the Linux server, but it does work in pfSense, so this particular question may just be being caused by other underlying problems.

Answer (score 0):

This actually ended up being an issue with Xen's virtual NIC drivers and pfSense 2.2.x. I am running pfSense in a Xen VM.

See: https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=88467.0

To fix it, you have to disable tx checksum offloading on the dom0 side. Run the following command on both of the vif's used by the pfSense VM:

```
ethtool -K vif123.0 tx off
```

Replace "123.0" with whatever your two vif's are.